# Streaming replication Postgresql 9.3 using two different servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Settings in master server:

```
max_wal_senders = 1
wal_level = 'archive'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
wal_keep_segments = 10000
```

Settings in slave server:
in recovery.conf file:

```
Standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=ipaddress of master user=repuser'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'
```

`log_connections=on` is set up on both master and slave server

entry is made for replication user in pg_hba.conf file in master server

```
host     replication     repuser         ipaddress/32         trust
```

when trying to replicate i get the following error

```
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2014-                                                                                        07-14 19:28:21 IST
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  entering standby mode
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data                                                                                         may be missing
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=min                                                                                        imal without taking a new base backup.
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/19FFE28
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/19FFE28
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the p                                                                                        rimary and standby
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6022019027749040119                                                                                        , the standby's identifier is 6033562405193904122.
2014-07-14 19:28:23 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:23 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:24 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:24 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:25 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:25 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:26 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:26 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:27 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:27 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
"postgresql-2014-07-14_192822.log" 6630L, 756429C
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2014-07-14 19:28:21 IST
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  entering standby mode
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/19FFE28
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/19FFE28
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2014-07-14 19:28:22 IST DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6022019027749040119, the standby's identifier is 6033562405193904122.
2014-07-14 19:28:23 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:23 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:24 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:24 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:25 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:25 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:26 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:26 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:27 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:27 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:28 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:28 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:29 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:29 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:30 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:30 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:31 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:31 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:32 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:32 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:33 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:33 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:34 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:34 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:35 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:35 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:36 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:36 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:37 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:37 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:37 IST FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2014-07-14 19:28:37 IST DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6022019027749040119, the standby's identifier is 6033562405193904122.
2014-07-14 19:28:38 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2014-07-14 19:28:38 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-07-14 19:28:39 IST LOG:  connection received: host=[local]

IST FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2014-07-14 19:28:37 IST DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6022019027749040119, the standby's identifier is 6033562405193904122.
```

What do these lines mean?

when I run this command

```
service postgresql-9.3 start
```

I get the following error in startup.log file

```
2014-07-15 11:25:59 IST FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2014-07-15 11:25:59 IST HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 25961) running in data directory "/opt/postgres/PostgreSQL/9.3/data"?
```

**Extend the question**

We are new to Postgresql open source. We couldn’t understand the answer to this question. Please if possible explain briefly. We have followed the instructions from the book 'Postgresql 9 Administration Cook book'.  We followed these steps from this book.

Carry out the following steps:

1. Identify your Master and Standby nodes, and ensure that they have been configured according to the best practice recipe.
2. Configure replication security. Create or confirm the existence of the replication user on Master node

   ```
   CREATE USER repuser 
   SUPERUSER 
   LOGIN 
   CONNECTION LIMIT 1 
   ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'changeme';
   ```
3. Allow the replication user to authenticate. The following example allows access from any ip address using encrypted password authentication; you may wish to consider more restrictive options. Add the following line:

   ```
   host replication repuser 127.0.0.1/0 md5
   ```
4. Set logging options in postgresql.conf on both Master and Standby, so that you get increased information regarding replication connection attempts and associated failures.

   ```
   log_connections = on
   ```
5. Set max_wal_senders on Master in `postgresql.conf`, or increment if the value is already non-zero.

   ```
   max_wal_senders = 1 
   wal_mode = 'archive' 
   archive_mode = on 
   archive_command = 'cd .'
   ```
6. Adjust wal_keep_segments on Master in postgresql.conf. Set this to a value no higher than the amount of freespace on the drive on which the pg_xlog directory is mounted, divided by 16MB. If pg_xlog isn't mounted on a separate drive, then don't assume all of the current freespace is available for transaction log files.

   ```
   wal_keep_segments = 10000 # e.g. 160 GB
   ```
7. Adjust hot Standby parameters if required (see later recipe)
8. Take a base backup, very similar to the process for taking a physical backup as described in the backup chapter.

   a. Start the backup

   ```
       psql -c "select pg_start_backup('base backup for streaming rep')"
   ```

   b. Copy the data files (excluding the pg_xlog directory)

   ```
       rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* \ 
       ${PGDATA}/ $STANDBYNODE:$PGDATA
   ```

   c. Stop the backup

   ```
      psql -c "select pg_stop_backup(), current_timestamp"
   ```
9. Set the `recovery.conf` parameters on the Standby. Note that the primary_ conninfo must not specify a database name, though can contain any other PostgreSQL connection option. Note also that all options in recovery.conf are enclosed in quotes, whereas postgresql.conf parameters need not be.

   ```
   Standby_mode = 'on' 
   primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.0.1 user=repuser' 
   trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'
   ```
10. Start Standby server
11. Carefully monitor replication delay until the catchup period is over. During the initial catchup period, the replication delay will be much higher than we would normally expect it to be. You are advised to set hot_Standby = off for the initial period only.

Comment: Answer updated. I think I was right about what happened, it just wasn't clear why with the information available. I'm still guessing since I can't know what exactly you really did, but hopefully this'll help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You seem to be trying to replicate from one server to another that wasn't set up using a copy of the original server. That's why:

> database system identifier differs between the primary and standby. The primary's identifier is 6022019027749040119, the standby's identifier is 6033562405193904122.

Because each newly `initdb`'d PostgreSQL gets a new random system identifier. When you copy an existing PostgreSQL install, it keeps the same system identifier. That's how PostgreSQL can keep track of whether one server can replay WAL from another.

You can only use physical replication if the replica is a copy (file-system level backup e.g. `pg_basebackup`) of the master. See the manual's detailed coverage on replication for more information.

---

**Update**:

The instructions shown above should be fine, but they're not as clear as they could be.

The standby server's data directory is supposed to be *replaced by* the base backup you create at step 8, if it exists in the first place.

You can't make an existing PostgreSQL instance into a standby for another without replacing its data directory. You need a copy of the master's data directory to run a standby. A common way to set that up is to take an existing standby, delete its data directory, replace it with a copy of the master's data directory, and then configure it as a replication slave. That's what I think step 8 is supposed to be doing.

Instead of doing that I think you probably used an existing data directory for the slave and tried to start it up as a replica of the master. That will not work, and will result in the errors you showed.

The [main PostgreSQL documentation on replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) is the recommended and primary resource for information. I suggest going there first.

You might also want to check out [repmgr](http://repmgr.org/), which helps automate replication and failover tasks.